# IOException when talking to Solr using HTTPS

Tags: spring-boot, solr

Working on springboot application which connect to solr. In application.properties file I have mention `spring.data.solr.host=https://somedomin:8983/solr` .When I refer to springboot-solr related documents the host is mentioned as http. But in my case it should be https.

```
org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: IOException occured when talking to server at: https://somedomin:8983/solr; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: https://somedomin:8983/solr
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:171) ~[spring-data-solr-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveBean(SolrTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-data-solr-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SimpleSolrRepository.save(SimpleSolrRepository.java:150) ~[spring-data-solr-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SimpleSolrRepository.save(SimpleSolrRepository.java:143) ~[spring-data-solr-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: https://somedomin:8983/solr
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:657) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:255) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:244) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:194) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:173) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.lambda$saveBean$2(SolrTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-data-solr-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:167) ~[spring-data-solr-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: somedomin: 443 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:542) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:255) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:244) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:194) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:173) ~[solr-solrj-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0 9060ac689c270b02143f375de0348b7f626adebc - jpountz - 2018-06-18 16:55:14]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.lambda$saveBean$2(SolrTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-data-solr-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:167) ~[spring-data-solr-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
```

How to convert the https to http of solr host.

Comment: Can you connect to the Solr server on https? Is the certificate valid or self-signed?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect but in the process of saving the metadata it is throwing the above error